# why i can't get the data form Model.all() using google app engine

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

this is my code in main.py

```
class marker_data(db.Model):
    geo_pt = db.GeoPtProperty()
class HomePage(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        a=marker_data()
        a.geo_pt=db.GeoPt(-34.397, 150.644)
        a.put()
        datas=marker_data.all()
        self.render_template('3.1.html',{'datas':datas})
```

and in the html is :

```
    {% for i in datas %}
        console.log(i)
    {% endfor %}
```

but the error is:

```
i is not defined
```

so what can i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'i' is interpreted by the templating engine on the server side, so you need:

```
{% for i in datas %}
    console.log({{ i }});
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax error sje397 mentioned, the .all() method returns a [Query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) object and I think you'll need to call .fetch(n) or .get() on that to retrieve the actual `marker_data` objects.

```
datas=marker_data.all().fetch(100)
```

Comment: `Query` objects are iterable, and automatically call `fetch()` for you (in batches of 20, I think) behind the scenes when they are iterated over: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html